# How can I fix this error "conversion from 'B' to non-scalar type 'D' requested"? (trying to do the "operator+" between the fields of the base class)

Tags: c++11

given the following code:

```
class B {
private:
    int n;
public:
    B(int x) :
            n(x) {
    }
    B operator+(const B& b) {
        return B(n + b.n);
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const B& b) {
        out << "B: " << b.n;
        return out;
    }
    bool operator<(const B& rhs) const {
        return n < rhs.n;
    }
};

class D: public B {
    double m;
public:
    D() :
            B(0), m(0) {
    }
    D(int x, int y) :
            B(x), m(y) {
    }
    D operator+(const D& d) {
        D result = B::operator+(d); // error
        result.m = m + d.m;
        return result;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const D& d) {
        out << static_cast<const B&>(d);
        out << ", D: " << d.m;
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b4(4);
    D d1(1, 0), d2(1, 2), d3 = d1 + d2;
    cout << b4 << ", " << d3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix the error?

> conversion from 'B' to non-scalar type 'D' requested

My purpose is to do the operation of the addition between the fields of the base class (`B`) ..

Comment: Do you need something like D result((B)d + (B)(*this));  It would require a new constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need more constructors.

I've managed to work round the error with:

new constructor for `D`:

```
D(const B& b): B(b), m(0){}
```

Output:

```
B: 4, B: 2, D: 2
```

I'm not exactly sure why this constructor is needed, but without it there is no conversion from `B` to `D`. Apparently as you noted, a copy constructor for `B` is not needed (I think the compiler writes one for you.)

The line:

```
D result = B::operator+(d);
```

invokes the conversion constructor above and not any sort of assignment operator.

Comment: Cab you explain how you will fix it with these constructors?